# React - sharing variables through useContext, to update and re-render components, but not working

Tags: reactjs, mern, use-effect

I am creating an exercise app (using MERN stack and graphql)
where it takes keywords from the user and fetches youtube videos matching those keywords.

After fetching the youtube data, I save that exercise in my mongoDB database, and also saved them in an array `exerciseArr`. This `exerciseArr` is a shared through different react components, through useContext.

The fetching request and receiving data happens in my `ExerciseForm` component.

I am using `ExerciseList` component to render those fetched exercises(saved in `exerciseArr`), whenever there is an update in `exerciseArr`, it should re-render items in `exerciseArr` to `ExerciseVideo`. That is happening in `useEffect` of `ExerciseList` component.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('exerciseArr in ExerciseList', exerciseArr)

        const fetchedExercises = exerciseArr.map( exercise => ( 
            <ExerciseVideo key={exercise._id} 
                id={exercise._id} 
                bodysection={exercise.bodysection}
                duration={exercise.duration}
                title={exercise.title} 
                videoUrl={exercise.videoUrl} 
                favorite={exercise.favorite}/>))
        
        setVideoElements(fetchedExercises)

    }, [exerciseArr])
```

The issue now is that `ExerciseList` component only renders with 1st request from `ExerciseForm`, and it does not re-render, unless you initiate some action(click event etc) with the already rendered video elements which is the prat of the `ExerciseList` component.

My understanding is that every time there is an update of `exerciseArr`, useEffect in ExerciseList would re-render. But this is not happening?

To force to re-render the `ExrciseList` component, I need to initiate click event or any sorts, with already existing `ExerciseVideo` elements which is part of the `ExerciseList` component.

This is how I render `ExerciseList` component in `App`

```
....
function App() {
  const { isAuth, exerciseArr } = useContext(Context)
  const hasExercise = exerciseArr.length > 0
  // const authenticatedView = <><ExerciseForm/></> 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <NavBar />
              <Manual />
              { isAuth ? <ExerciseForm/> : <Login/> }
              { isAuth && hasExercise ? <ExerciseList /> : ''}
          </Route>
....
```

I wonder if I am not using useEffect in `ExerciseList` component correctly, in order to re-render itself. Or how I am rendering `ExerciseList` component in `App` needs to change.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: is the exerxiseList depends on some keys that user uses to fetch data?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error which was causing the problem.

The `useEffect` function is correct, but the `if` statement where it should render and update the `exerciseArr` was returning false.

```
            if(resData.data.exercises.__typename === 'ExerciseData') {
                //then save those results in exerciseArr
                const graphqlResponse = resData.data.exercises.exercises
                return setExerciseArr(graphqlResponse)
            }
```

this block's `resData.data.exercises.__typename` path was not correct before.
Thus not updating the `exerciseArr` at all.

*sidenote, I moved this `useEffect` function into `Context` and only render `exerciseArr` in `ExerciseList` to create video div elements now, to make component more simple.